# Nested NSOperation and isFinished status

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a NSOperation Operation1 that contains a queue with a NSOperation Operation2. I would like to know if Operation1 needs that Operation2 is finished to change its status to isFinished. I think it should but can you confirm? Thanks !
Bertrand

Comment: Only you can answer this question.  No one else knows what the requirement is.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if Operation1 needs that Operation2 is finished
>   to change its status to isFinished. I think it should but can you
>   confirm?

The isFinished flag of Operation1 needs to be set to YES, if any of the following conditions are met:
1) if the Operation1 is cancelled
2) if Operation1 completes the task that it is supposed to do. What Operation1 is supposed to do is something you will need to explain in little more detail. But based on the detail you have provided (that Operation1 contains a queue with Operation2), Operation2 will need to be finished (either by completing its task, or by being cancelled), in order for operation1 to be marked as finished.